# How to create a built-Up area from multiple polygons?

Tags: arcgis-pro, cartography

I have been struggling over the last few days to emulate an old American map for a city.

I have a shapefile for the buildings of the city, but since they are almost few hundreds, I was trying to combine them together in order to get Built-Up urban areas (blocks) instead. Arcgis Pro provides a feature called Delineate Built-Up Areas but I failed to merge my buildings into different block.

Regards

[image]

Comment: It looks like to me you want a convexhull tool to create your urban blocks. You may need to regroup your building area before using convexhull to your group of features.

Comment: Does the convex hull need any kind of license? I could not find this tool in my arcgis pro.

Comment: Its called Minimum bounding geometry. Does all building in each block have a common attribute, for example "block id"?

Comment: I don't know, not so familiar with arcgis, here is the doc :https://pro.arcgis.com/fr/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/minimum-bounding-geometry.htm. You want to create a map with generalisation style, but do you really need this blocks as geometry ? if not, it may be more usefull to look in the settings of your map renderer ...

Comment: @BERA The Geometry Type options Convex hull, Circle, and Envelope are only available with an ArcGIS Desktop Advanced license.

Comment: @BERA I extracted the data from Openstreetmap so each building has osm_id and type attribute as well. Should I group them based on these attribute before applying the Minimum bounding geometry?

Comment: Dissolve by some Group id, then minimum bounding geometry (try the types you have with your license, like rectangle by area, or rectangle by width)